# Using hector quadrotor with Gazebo 1.9 (or current bleeding edge version)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear all,

I am currently trying to get the hector-quadrotor uav to work with the new version of Gazebo (downloaded from source). I managed to install Gazebo and use it as described in the tutorials but when I try to run the hector quadrotor demo (described in the tutorial), Gazebo 1.5 runs instead the simulator-gazebo package is installed with the hector-quadrotor-demo package. Could someone kindly point out how to spawn the UAV in the new version of Gazebo (all i need to do is spawn the uav and control it I do not need to run the tutorials).

Thanks in advance,

JP

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3488/using-hector-quadrotor-with-gazebo-1.9-(or-current-bleeding-edge-version)/) by [jpcallus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/391/jpcallus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2013-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you might try to start gazebo and then just spawn hector directly:

```
roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

and

```
roslaunch hector_quadrotor_gazebo spawn_quadrotor.launch
```

The hector launch files that are starting gazebo are not updated to **gazebo_ros** yet...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpcallus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/391/jpcallus/) on 2013-07-10**:
cheers mate...that worked :)